# searching sequences in strings of IP addresses

Tags: python, excel, algorithm, matlab

I have these strings in a file, which are IP addresses.

```
D192,D168,D12,D10
D192,D168,D12,B00010001
D192,D168,D12,D12
D192,D168,D12,D13

D192,D168,D13,D10
D192,D168,D13,D11
```

and I want to find continuous values, and merge them
like this:

```
D192,D168,D12,B000100xx
D192,D168,D13,B0001000x
```

D,B are for decimal and binary formats.
And x can only be 1 or 0. so each portion could be from 0 to 255.

but I dont know how to do this? should I change each portion to an integer, and then split each line by "," and compare values of each part?

I want to do this in python at last, but first I can use Excel or even Matlab to check if I do it right!

Comment: You didn't add a language tag.

Comment: Please precise *continous values*, it's ambiguous. I'm not sure how you produced exemplary result. For example, with current problem definition, `D192,D168,D1x,B000100xx` or `D192,D168,D1xxxxxxxxxxx` also are correct results.

Comment: Thank you both.and sorry I forgot to mention the details